# phonegap / cordova audio issue with Samsung S3 (and others)

Tags: cordova, audio, phonegap-build, html5-audio, samsung-mobile

I recently published a Phonegap / Cordova app, with sounds. It plays nice with most phones. However, some complaints were made, that no sound is played on several phones. I found one of the models is Samsung S3. 
I managed to create a simplified app, that demonstrates this issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1 id="ogg">OGG</h1>
<h1 id="wav">WAV</h1>
<h1 id="mp3">MP3</h1>

<script>
  var ogg = document.getElementById("ogg"),
      oggSound = new Audio('bark04.ogg'),
      wav = document.getElementById("wav"),
      wavSound = new Audio('bark04.wav'),
      mp3 = document.getElementById("mp3"),
      mp3Sound = new Audio('bark04.mp3');

      ogg.onclick = function(){
        console.log("Start ogg");
        oggSound.play();
        console.log("Done ogg");
      }
      wav.onclick = function(){
        console.log("Start wav");
        wavSound.play();
        console.log("Done wav");
      }
      mp3.onclick = function(){
        console.log("Start mp3");
        oggSound.play();
        console.log("Done mp3");
      }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Several notes here:

- This code works well when I use the android browser to look at the page. Only when I compile it using Phonegap 6.4.6 / Cordova 6.5.0, there any issue.
- This code works well on several phones, including Samsung S5
- Using android "about:inspect", I saw that all console.log outputs appear, and there are no errors.
- Both mp3 / ogg files were created using Audacity from the same wav. Both are kinda short. I couldn't think of any file format that did work.
  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a not-so-satisfying solution. I found that installing phonegap with crosswalk plugin solves the problem. This is not a great solution, as it requires 2 larger APKs, but for now - it's the best I got so... I'll take it.